# Is there a way to manage the number of ticks on the nvd3 chart

Tags: jquery, charts, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 charts in my application and was wondering if there is a way I can customize the number of ticks on the x-axis. When I have a lot of data points, the tick labels overlap and look pretty bad. I searched online and found a few suggestions like using tickValues() and ticks() but not entirely sure how to use them.

Note: I am not using times but custom labels on the ticks on the x-axis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

I was able to resolve the overlap issue by using [axis.ticks(count)](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_ticks). This allowed me to set a maximum count for the number of ticks I want displayed on my chart.

Thank you.